# Open root zarr with multiple groups using xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, zarr

Suppose I had a zarr file that has n groups each of which have only one zarr array and share at least 3 dimensions but may have others as well, how would I load an xarray Dataset from said zarr root file while aligning their common dimensions and preserving attributes?

Currently I am experimenting with a hack where I list the individual zarr groups using glob and feeding them as a list to `xr.open_mfdataset(list_of_zarr_groups,engine=‘zarr’`, but surely there must be a better way.

Comment: The ability to work with multiple groups and other tree-like/hierarchical structures is part of the [xarray development roadmap](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.06.0/roadmap.html#flexible-data-structures). But for now, your approach sounds fine!

Answer (score 2):

Using [xarray-datatree](https://github.com/xarray-contrib/datatree) you can open all groups in a Zarr store at once as a single `DataTree` object. You can then extract the different groups as individual `xarray.Dataset` objects. Just call `datatree.open_datatree(zarr_store, engine="zarr")`.

(As @michael-delgado said, this is being actively developed as part of the xarray roadmap.)